# How to update a React component based on a context array value

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Good morning,

I have been struggling with this Next.JS problem during the week, because we have a list of objects in a component that comes from the value of an array in a context.

### Introduction

The issue here is:

1. That we have `setSessionList` that is a setter for a React state in the context.
2. `sessionList` that is an array of objects in the context
3. and the component `InspectionLongList`, that is the list itself, where all this objects are rendered and structured.

### Question and doubts

1. Is it possible to conditionally update `InspectionLongList` when other component of the app updates a value of an object in the array `sessionList`, using `setSessionList` from the context?
2. Which is the good approach to do this?

### Some code (for context)

The context:

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

interface IGobalState {


  setSessionList: (value: any) => void;
  sessionList: any;

}


export const AppContext = createContext({} as IGobalState);

export function AppWrapper({ children }: any) {


  const [sessionList, setSessionList] = useState<any>([]);


  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        
        sessionList,
        setSessionList,
        
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}




export function useAppContext() {
  return useContext(AppContext);
}
```

And the consumer (wrapped in the Provider)

```js
 const {setSessionList, sessionList} = useAppContext();




  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.auth.isLoggedIn === true){
      
      apiService.getAllInspections(props.auth.user.accessToken).then(res => setSessionList(res))
    } 
   
  }, [sessionList, setSessionList])
```

### UPDATE: How we consume the context for updates (InspectionLongList)

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    
    if (props.auth.isLoggedIn === true){
      
       apiService.getAllInspections(props.auth.user.accessToken).then(res => setSessionList(res))

   }

    
  }, [JSON.stringify(sessionList)]);
```

Thanks in advance,
Carles

Comment: What problem do you encounter? Using either `useEffect` or event handler to update context state are ways to achieve the goal.

Comment: The fact is, that when I update a value in the array, the component that renders the list does not update.

Comment: Can you be more specific? And update your code so as to reflect how you want to "conditionally update `InspectionLongList` when `sessionList` gets updated"

Comment: using  `const {setSessionList, sessionList} = useAppContext();` we get `sessionList`and after that, .map the `sessionList`on the `InspectionLongList`

Comment: I don't see, from your current snippet and explanations, how do you try to update `InspectionLongList` when `sessionList` gets updated. Please paste relevent code with the the said `InspectionLongList`, and provide a minimun produced sandbox.

Comment: Okay, I have just updated it. Kindly check it.

Comment: Hey @Enfieldli, are you available to check this?

Comment: Hello @Enfieldli could you help us with this topic?